# Should I require a specific condition when working with indexes in Solidity?

Tags: programming-languages, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract A{
    byte[10] arr;

    function setElement(uint index, byte value) public {
        require(index >= 0 && index < arr.length); //Should I leave it as is?
        arr[index] = value;
    }

    function getElement(uint index) view public returns (byte) {
        require(index >= 0 && index < arr.length); //Or not?
        return arr[index];
    }
}
```

As I know an assert-style exception is generated in the following situations and not only:

- If you access an array at a too large or negative index (i.e. x[i] where i >= x.length or i < 0).

But should I check the condition every time?

Also I would like to refund the remaining gas to the executor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using it correctly. `require` is intended to be used to check input parameters whereas `assert` is to verify the internals of your contract (mostly for testing purposes). If a `require` condition fails, the remaining gas will be refunded.

From the [Solidity documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/control-structures.html?highlight=require#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions):

> The convenience functions assert and require can be used to check for
>   conditions and throw an exception if the condition is not met. The
>   assert function should only be used to test for internal errors, and
>   to check invariants. The require function should be used to ensure
>   valid conditions, such as inputs, or contract state variables are met,
>   or to validate return values from calls to external contracts.